# Conditional join so to ignore null values

Tags: join, null

I am trying to Join between two tables

e.g.

```
Label    Name  
--------------
UK      United Kingdom  
EU      Europe  
LON     London  

Region    Country     City     Amount  
EU        [NULL]      [NULL]   100.00  
EU        UK          [NULL]    50.00  
EU        UK          LON       20.00
```

I want to link the two tables so I have the label so a table as follows:

```
Region Code   Region    Country Code    Country   City Code    City   Amount  
EU            Europe    [NULL]          [NULL]    [NULL]       [NULL] 100.00  
EU            Europe    UK              United... [NULL]       [NULL]  50.00
```

etc...

I am having trouble linking - I want to say if its null don't worry about getting a label.  I have done a number of left outer joins, but it is incredibly slow.  Is there a straightforward way of joining with conditions?

Many thanks,
Lydia.

Answer (score 0):

"If its null then don't worry about getting a label" So.. if the label is null, then just make it null? Don't worry about conditions, just join and allow the nulls to come through.

```
SELECT t1.region, 
    t1.country as country_code, 
    t2.name as country, 
    t1.city as city_code, 
    t3.name as city, 
    t1.amount
FROM mainTable t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN labelTable t2 ON
        t1.country = t2.label
    LEFT OUTER JOIN labelTable t3 ON
        t1.city = t3.label
```

Null `Name` fields (either because of an existing `label` with a `null` `name`, or because the `label` doesn't exist in `labeltable`) will be `Null` as you want.

Comment: Many thanks JNevill.   This does work but it is taking a very long time to run so I might investigate some other options.

Comment: Consider indexing on the fields with which you are joining these three tables. Short of denormalizing your data into a 4th table and just querying that straight, Indexing is your best here.

Comment: Thank you - that's been helpful